# Why does pt-table-checksum gives exit status 0 if slave is unreachable?

Tags: percona-tools

I'm using `pt-table-checksum` version `2.1.4` for checking my master-slave set up. In the case when I forget to set up the right privileges on the slave, it writes an error to `stderr` like this:

```
# pt-table-checksum -d employees
Cannot connect to h=node03.mydomain.local                                 <== error
            TS ERRORS  DIFFS     ROWS  CHUNKS SKIPPED    TIME TABLE
10-04T15:33:33      0      0        9       1       0   0.014 employees.departments
[...]
```

However, the exit status of it is `0`.

```
# echo $?
0
```

The number differences it will find is always zero, as it has nothing to compare against. And yes, documentation says to exit with status `0` if no differences or errors have been reported. But this does not make sense in most cases.

Is there a way to make `pt-table-checksum` not failing silently and reporting this as a general failure? Should I file a bug or is this configurable?

<sup>It proves to be confusing to more users, for example in this question: ["pt-table-checksum help required"](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/20564/pt-table-checksum-help-required).</sup>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pt-table-checksum` runs on the master primarily, but as binary logging on MySQL is statement based, the actual calculation statements are being executed on the slave as well. One should then run `pt-table-checksum` on the slave to check and compare the checksums it can't access the slave from the master. Add the `--replicate-check-only` option to have it only check for differences based on the checksums already present in the checksums table.